# Good name for a set of vectors with uniform pairwise angles?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

I am writing a paper and I have a set of $N$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d$ ($d>N$) whose all pairwise angles are the same. What is a succinct but mathematically accurate name for this set?

Answer (score 1):

The term https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equiangular_lines

may fit the bill. Each pair of distinct vectors have the same inner product.

Comment: I think this is close, but not quite the same. For example, I can’t have a set of 3 vectors of 2-dimensional vectors with the same pairwise angles. But I can have E equiangular lines in 2D.

Comment: Sorry I meant 3 instead of E.

Comment: @CWC If no established name turns up, I guess “(pairwise) equiangular vectors” could work?

Comment: @CWC And to your first comment, why doesn’t $\{e^{i2\pi k/3}\mid k=0,1,2\}$ work for you?

Comment: @Milten Ah silly me. I see your point. Yes three vectors arranged 120 degrees apart from each other would satisfy my requirement in 2D. My gut feeling is that the upper bound on the size of my set and equiangular line set would be different at higher dimensional space. But I think for the name “equiangular vector” would do fine. Thanks!

Comment: @CWC just curious, what's wrong with equiangular lines?